# Import cannot be resolved in eclipse due to the import of specific lib in an existing project

Tags: java, eclipse, import, lib

I have some import errors on a project that I have to repair (which has been written by someone else). That's a java web scraper, and the developer choose to import :

```
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.host.file.FileReader;
import com.sun.glass.events.WindowEvent;
import com.toedter.calendar.JDateChooser;
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
```

(and lot of other lib.)

The error is always the same : "The import  cannot be resolved."
I guess that I have to add some file in the project path or something like that, but I don't exactly know how, where and what.

Can someone help me ?

Big thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is an eclipse issue. Try to clean the project(`Project > Clean`). And double-check that your build path contains all the required jars(with no errors). May also be useful to check if there is some useful information in the "Problems" view.

Comment: okay, I had missing jars ! I choose to rebuild the project with Maven to solve all dependency problem automatically. Thanks !